# Is multiple classified jars with a single pom in artifactory normal?

Tags: java, maven

We are using classifiers to build two types of jars: java6 and java7.  The idea is to keep them separate because of differences in dependencies.

In artifactory I see both of the jars with proper classifiers.  This is good.  However, in the directory I only see a single POM.  The POM always has the timestamp of the last built jar, eg `1.0.30-20150325.220019-8`.  This means that if I build a java6 jar, followed by a java7 jar, then the pom will be timestamped the same as the java 7 jar.  The timestamp of the java 6 jar will not match the pom.  So one of the two classified jars always has a different snapshot version than the pom.

Initially I was using maven 3.0.3 and java 6 refused to resolve the jar.  However switching to maven 3.2.5 resolved the issue.  It was never an issue in java 7.  Furthermore, after switching to maven 3.2.5 it worked so I thought "Thats how maven implemented it.  With a single shared pom."

Yesterday though we got an issue where a java 6 jar build was failing with a reference to the java 7 timestamp.  Even though the jar was there for java 6, just with an older timestamp.  This makes me wonder if maybe there is supposed to be two poms?  Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that all of the agents being used to compile and deploy had not been upgraded to maven 3.2.5.  Furthermore, TeamCity had had some manual configuration explicitly stating that a particular build us a specific maven version.

I added the maven enforcer plugin with the requirement that maven be at 3.2.5 to weed this out.  Afterwards, DevOps was able to easily see why a build had failed and do the appropriate fix.

To answer the other part of my question, a single POM is the implementation that happens locally and on Artifactory.  It works with the proper version of maven so I guess that is just how it was done.  Certainly is not backwards compatible in the cases I saw.